# token transfer using one account vs. multiple

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I'm trying to send tokens to multiple wallets as soon as possible.

A. function can be run by only one wallet under `onlyOwner`.

```
   function batchTransfer(address[] memory receivers, uint256[] memory amounts)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < receivers.length; i++) {
            _transfer(receivers[i], amounts[i]);
        }
    }
```

B. function can be run by 5 wallets registerd under `Authorized`.

```
   function batchTransfer(address[] memory receivers, uint256[] memory amounts)
        external
        Authorized
    {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < receivers.length; i++) {
            _transfer(receivers[i], amounts[i]);
        }
    }
```

Which would be faster to send tokens to multiple wallets?

Using 5 wallets to run function `B` at around the same time ***vs.*** Using one wallet to run function `A` 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple wallets to execute `case B` will reduce the overall time required to send tokens to multiple wallets. Still, it comes with some additional risks such as multiple calls will be generated to update the same state on the blockchain which might cause some issues.

So, its better to stick with `case A` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: thanks! then if I stick to case A, up to how many wallets can I send per transaction? any recommended or usual process to do that?

Comment: That depends on which blockchain you're using 
There is no specific number but I once did a transaction with loop of 250

Answer (score 1):

The speed of token transfers depends on network congestion, gas prices, and transaction execution time. It has nothing to do with the complexity of the function. A single `_transfer` will take as much time as `batchTransfer`

To determine to how many wallets you can send tokens to in a single transaction, you'll need to estimate the gas consumption per iteration in the loop.

In theory, you can use up to the block gas limit, which is 30M gas on most of the network. But in practice, it depends on how much you pay for gas and how the network is congested.

[Eth Gaslimit](https://etherscan.io/chart/gaslimit)

[Polygon Gaslimit](https://polygonscan.com/chart/gaslimit)

But from my experience on a **batch transfer**, you can easily send to up to 100 to 200 addresses.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know, but my question is whether I should run case `B` in parallel with multiple accounts to send tokens to more people than using only 1 account like case `A`